# How to remove the header from all pages except home?

Tags: theme-development, headers

I have a Template Monster WP theme that I need to remove the headers from all pages except home. I have read several posts on this, but my code is a bit different. Can someone please help me? The header.php file is below. Many thanks!

```
<div id="main"><!-- this encompasses the entire Web site -->
    <header id="header">
        <div class="container_12 clearfix">
            <div class="grid_12">
        <div class="logo">
          <?php if(of_get_option('logo_type') == 'text_logo'){?>
            <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
              <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" title="<?php 
               bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            <?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: In general, you should be asking questions of this type on your specific theme's help forum.

Comment: Your `header.php` should really be called on every page - it can *display* differently (or not output at all) - but it really should also be calling functions like [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) on every page.

Answer (score 2):

In the line before `<header id="header">`, put this code:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) : ?>
```

After the `</header>` tag that closes #header (which isn't included in your code), put this code:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `is_home()` is called a "template tag" and there are quite a few of them. If your site uses a static front page set on Settings > Reading, then replace `is_home()` with `is_front_page()`.